# How nft ruleset merge?

Tags: nftables

I have some nft rules configured on system A. I want to move all the rules from system A to system B. But on system B, I also have set some nft rules, and I need them.

If I do, on system A

```bash
nft list ruleset > ruleset-a.nft
```

Then on system B,

```bash
nft -f ruleset-a.nft
```

How will the ruleset from system A merge with the ruleset on system B?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you not experiment to figure out it and to share this knowledge with us?

Comment: If new ruleset has flush it replace old otherwise rules added. https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement